# Copy the value of 2 divs to a single output div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text boxes, one has an id and the other has a class. I need to copy the values in both of the text boxes to a single div when the button is clicked.
I have attempted this but only the second box's value is copied.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="test1" value="Hello World"/>
<input type="text" class="test2" value="Hello World Jquery"/>
<input type="submit" value="Select" id="button"/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#output').text($("#test1").val());   //assigns value to your div
        $('#output').text($(".test2").val());
    });   
});
```

Comment: This is because you are assigning value one after other. If you want both value, concat values and then assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

You can use the append functionality in jquery as shown below,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#button').click(function(){
    var output = $('#output');
    output.empty();
    output.append($("#test1").val());   //assigns value to your div
    output.append($(".test2").val());
});   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test1" value="Hello World"/>
<input type="text" class="test2" value="Hello World Jquery"/>
<input type="submit" value="Select" id="button"/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery text overwrites the value everytime you use it. So a solution is to store the value in some variable first and then write it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){ 
        var value = $("#test1").val() + $(".test2").val();
        $('#output').text(value); //assigns value to your div 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4o5n26ha/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $('#output').text($("#test1").val()+$(".test2").val()); //assigns value to your div

    });
});
```

In your code you are reassigning again the value of the div that is why only one is showing combine them by using `+` so both value will appear

Answer (score 0):

Value placed in div by clicking on button places test1 's value on div but replaced by next value (".test2").val();

use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/41c25qzs/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#button').click(function(){
$('#output').text($("#test1").val()+$(".test2").val());    

});   
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of just providing code.